# Java - Using iterators with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

I am new to the whole "iterator" concept in Java and need help with implementing it in my code. Here is the code:

```
class IteratorExample {

int tstArray [];

IteratorExample(){

}

public void addNum(int num){

   tstArray[0] = num; //And yes, I can only add one number at the moment, but it
                      is not what I want to focus on right now.
}


public Iterator<Integer> innerIterator(){
    return new methodIterator();
}

 class methodIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
    public int index;
    private methodIterator(){
        index = 0;
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        return index < tstArray.length;

    }
    public Integer next(){
        return;
    }


  }    

public static void main(String[] args){
    IteratorExample sample = new IteratorExample();
  test(sample);
}

public static void test(IteratorExample arr){
 arr.addNum(1);
 system.out.print(arr);
}

}
```

This is the code written so far. I want to make it so I can add a number to an array using the addNum() method and then display it from main using system.print (and yes, I am aware that I need a toString method in order for the numbers to come up instead of the memory-address, that will be implemented later on, right now I am only focused on getting this to work.)

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: *"And yes, I can only add one number at the moment, but it is not what I want to focus on right now."* - Actually, it is what you **should** be focusing on.  'Cos it includes infrastructure that the iterator needs.

Comment: Why are you trying to add an iterator to a non-collection type?

Comment: I am trying to compare the run speed between an array and and arraylist with iterators. It is unconventional(and may I add not practical?) but that is the real reason.

Comment: you can't print the memory address btw

Comment: @SleimanJneidi You can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the `Iterator` work, the `next()` method could be

```
public Integer next(){
    return tstArray[index++];
}
```

This throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is too large, whereas the specification for `Iterator`  says it should throw a `NoSuchElementException`. In order to do it properly you could write

```
public Integer next(){
    if (index < tstArray.length)
        return tstArray[index++];
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```